# How to add missing values to vectors in R

Tags: r, vector

I have two vectors. The `year` vector corresponds to the year where some event was observed. The `count` vector lists the number of times the event was observed the corresponding year. For instance, 3 events were observed in 1940, 4 in 1942, and so on.

```
year <- c(1940, 1942, 1944, 1945)
count <- c(3, 4, 7, 2)
```

Now I would like to add the years where no event was observed in the `year` vector (e.g. 1941, 1943) along with a zero in the corresponding position in the `count` vector. In other words, I would like something like this:

```
year_new <- c(1940, 1941, 1942, 1943, 1944, 1945)
count_new <- c(3, 0, 4, 0, 7, 2)
```

Any idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by converting your vectors to a dataframe, and merging that with a new dataframe with the full range of years:

```
year <- c(1940, 1942, 1944, 1945)
count <- c(3, 4, 7, 2)

df <- data.frame(year, count)

df <- merge(df, data.frame(year=seq(1940, 1945)), all.y=T)

df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

And if you want your data back as vectors and not a dataframe:

```
year <- df$year
count <- df$count
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, it is better to keep these vectors in dataframe, however, here is one way dealing with vectors

```
newyear <- min(year) : max(year)
newcount <- count[match(newyear, year)]
newcount[is.na(newcount)] <- 0

newyear
#[1] 1940 1941 1942 1943 1944 1945

newcount
#[1] 3 0 4 0 7 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
    year <- c(1940, 1942, 1944, 1945)
    count <- c(3, 4, 7, 2)

#Include all years in the year new
    year_new <- min(year):max(year)
#Initialize the new count to 0s
    count_new <- rep(0, length(year_new))
#Update the places where previously a value existed with the old count value
    count_new[year_new %in% year] <- count
```

Answer (score 2):

As an attempt on a solved question for my first post on stack overflow:

You can get intended result with a loop as well:

```
year <- c(1940, 1942, 1944, 1945)
count <- c(3, 4, 7, 2)

year_new <- seq(min(year),max(year),1) # Create new year vector as requested
count_new <- vector(mode="integer",length = length(year_new))

timer <- 1# to compare next element in the "count" vector
for (i in 1:length(year_new)){
   if (year_new[i]==year[timer]){
     count_new[i]=count[timer] #update "count_new"
     timer <- timer+1 # update which element to select in "count"
}}
```

Though this is a much slower and inefficient code, the methodology can be applied with most software packages